# Google Forms + Cloud Function Integration

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-functions, google-forms

Image with Error:
[image: Image with Error]

Hi,

I am trying to build an OnSubmit Function with google forms. I have attached the picture of the error. As far as I understand, the gs script isn't able to read the property "response" from "event". I have clearly followed the Google Apps Script documentation. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: The event isn't there when you test the function, it's only there when you actually trigger the submit event. In other words testing will be a pain in the ass for that one, but the stackdriver logs might just be your friend.

Answer (score 1):

I would need a little more information in order to more accurately help. If you could specify why you are setting a trigger/ what it is that you want to do then I can hopefully help a little more.

However I can try to help from the little bit that I can see from your picture...
**step 1** to solving your problem: **Have you implemented a trigger?** All I see is that you created a function called "onSubmit". Unfortunately with google script, that doesn't do anything to actually tell the servers when to run the function. For that you would need to set a trigger. I would highly recommend that you create the code through the responses **google sheet** and not through the form itself. That is because if you wish to use the information from the form response, then using the google spreadsheet makes it significantly easier to retrieve the information, especially if you are familiar with arrays. [This is a short video of me doing the process of setting a trigger and showing you the results.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BEbF24M7G_4H7G9rwkqzRxpuRM4UPSp1?usp=sharing) The only thing I have redacted is my email.

Regardless of whether you decide to implement the code on the spreadsheet or the form, the steps for adding a trigger are the same.
What you want to do is go to your code. Click "edit" -> Click "Current Project's Triggers" -> click "Add trigger" -> and for "Select event type you want to select "On Form Submit"
The reason I specifically put "on form submit" is because that was my understanding of your problem. By selecting that it runs your selected function whenever the form is submitted.

Hope this helps. If you need further clarification, please let me know.